# Why am I getting: TypeError: _axios.default.get.mockResolvedValue is not a function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, axios

Here's the error:

```
    TypeError: _axios.default.get.mockResolvedValue is not a function

      20 |         ]
      21 |     }
    > 22 |     Axios.get.mockResolvedValue(response);
         |               ^
      23 | 
      24 |     const component = renderer.create(
      25 |         <BookList />
```

Here's my code:

```
import React from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import {shallow, mount, render} from "enzyme";

import BookList from "../BookList";

import renderer from "react-test-renderer";

jest.mock('Axios');

test("<BookList /> snapshot test", () => {
    const response = {
        data: [
            {
                title: "foo"
            },
            {
                title: "bar"
            }
        ]
    }
    Axios.get.mockResolvedValue(response);

    const component = renderer.create(
        <BookList />
    )
    let tree = component.toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
})
```

Answer (score 8):

You are getting this error because `mockResolvedValue` doesn't exist in `Axios.post`. You'll have to type case it as necessary

```
(Axios.get as jest.Mock<{}>).mockResolvedValue(response);
```

Also, make sure you initialise the value of Axios.get as necessary. Like

```
Axios.get = jest.fn()
```

---

Also

```
jest.mock('Axios');
```

must be

```
jest.mock('axios');
```

Comment: What does `jest.mock('axios')` do? Does it just create a dummy object called `axios` that exists in the same scope?

Comment: @BlaineLafreniere `jest.mock` takes in the import path and not the name. E.g, to mock Booklist from your code, you have to do `jest.mock("../BookList")`

Comment: @BlaineLafreniere I was getting the same problem but for me the jest.mock('axios') was in my describe() statement. Once I placed it outside of it, I was able to access mockResolvedValue() function. I think your issue was just the capitalization of axios on the import.